# Close Chrome extension options

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Chrome added a new way to show the options of an extension in version 40.
The only way to close this overlay is to click on the small 'x' at the top right. You cannot even close it by clicking outside the window.

I want to add a button to my extension's option page to close the options.
I know there is a method to open the options page: chrome.runtime.openOptionsPage().

Is there an equivalent to close the options?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From within the options page, you can call `window.close()`, which will close the overlay.